# Google API Gateway configuration for a Cloud Run Server that serves GraphQL at endpoint /api

Tags: google-api, graphql, openapi, google-cloud-run

I have a running backend server that serves GraphQL on endpoint `/api`. Works like a charme but I still have it externally open and access is possible without authentication.

[image]

So I started trying the API Gateway beta Google just released. All that was pretty straight forward expcept the part where I have to configure the OpenAPI 2.0 configuration YAML.

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: myapp-backend-graphql-api
  description: "API for GraphQL queries and mutations"
  version: "1.0.0"
schemes:
  - "https"
paths:
  "/api":
    post:
      description: "GraphQL Endpoint"
      operationId: "graphqlEndpoint"
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://myapp-backend-43Jasfasd-ew.a.run.app
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: GraphQl
          schema:
            type: object
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Success."
          schema:
            type: object
```

So this is my `openapi-config.yml`. I somewhat struggled a b

---

it defining the "REST" endpoint here since I have a GraphQL endpoint. But it's just a POST request, right? So nothing usual for OpenAPI 2.0 I thought.

Anyways the API Gateway was created successfully according to GCP
[image]

However - calling the API now via the Gateway URL `https://mystuff-api-9kytelt5.ew.gateway.dev` and the endpoint `/api` fails.

```
xetra11@pop-os:~$ curl https://mystuff-api-9kytelt5.ew.gateway.dev/api/schema.json 
{"message":"Path does not match any requirement URI template.","code":404}
```

I am somewhat lost with that error message and don't know where I have to adjust something.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue @xetra11?

Answer (score 1):

In your openapi-config.yml file, like the example [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run#endpoints_configure), you need to add the host just above the schemes entry. The host is the hostname portion of the URL that Cloud Run creates. Also your path and scheme have double quotes which it doesn't need to be. I made some modification to your example, see if that helps.

Example:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: myapp-backend-graphql-api
  description: "API for GraphQL queries and mutations"
  version: "1.0.0"
host: myapp-backend-43Jasfasd-ew.a.run.app
schemes:
  - https
paths:
  /api:
    post:
      description: "GraphQL Endpoint"
      operationId: "graphqlEndpoint"
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://myapp-backend-43Jasfasd-ew.a.run.app
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: GraphQl
          schema:
            type: object
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          schema:
            type: object
```

Comment: I added the `host` now. However it still renders the same error. Isn't the error a sign that the API Gateway is working but I just don't have access through it?

Comment: It just means it can't get to the service configuration, you can verify this in your build logs. It is very important to change the service config with every new deployment of the managed service. 

1. Upload a new OpenAPI configuration and receive the new CONFIG_ID.
2. Rebuild the ESPv2 container image that will use the CONFIG_ID as the reference to have the new OpenAPI configuration.
3. Execute a Cloud Run deployment of the newly built ESPv2 + OpenAPI configuration container.

See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/esp-v2/issues/140#issuecomment-621485384 for more info.

Comment: What with every deployment? I am running on Google Cloud with Cloud Build and mainline deployments. That won't be very convenient..

Answer (score 0):

You only defined the POST verb in your openAPI spec. add a `-X POST` to your curl command to change the default GET verb to POST